# Failing to send form data to email

Tags: php, html

Hi all i have designed a page which has online registration form, i want filled form data to be sent to email id, for that i have used below code,

```
$to = 'example@example.com';

$subject = 'I need to show html'; 

$from ='from@from.com'; 

$body = '<p style=color:red;>This text should be red</p>';

ini_set("sendmail_from", $from);

$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\nReply-To: " . $from . "";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {

  echo("<p>Sent</p>");
 } else {
  echo("<p>Error...</p>");
 }
```

I have hosted this using free web hosting to test, everything works fine but submitted details doesnt come mentioned email id, i am really new to this ,can some one help me out

**Here is the Form Code:**

```
<body>

<?php


// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $cnameErr = $mobilenoErr = $emailErr = $cityErr= $postalcodeErr = $addressErr = "";

$name = $cname = $mobileno = $email = $city= $postalcode = $address = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) { 
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["cname"])) {
     $cnameErr = "Company Name is required";
   } else {
     $cname = test_input($_POST["cname"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["mobileno"])) {
     $mobilenoErr = "Mobile Number is required";
   }else {
     $mobileno = test_input($_POST["mobileno"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[789][0-9]{9}$/",$mobileno)) {
       $mobilenoErr = "Not A Valid Number"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address is well-formed
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
     }
   }
   if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
     $cityErr = "City is required";
   }  else {
     $city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city)) {
       $cityErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }
   if (empty($_POST["postalcode"])) {
     $postalcodeErr = "Postal Code is required";
   } else {
     $postalcode = test_input($_POST["city"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
     $addressErr = "Address is required";
   } else {
     $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
   }
}

$to = 'example@Example.com';

$subject = 'I need to show html'; 

$from ='from@from.com'; 

$body = '<p style=color:red;>This text should be red</p>';

$body .= '<label>User Name:</label>'.$name.'<br>';

$body .= '<label>Company Name:</label>'.$cname.'<br>';


ini_set("sendmail_from", $from);

$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\nReply-To: " . $from . "";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {

  echo("<p>Sent</p>");
 } else {
  echo("<p>Error...</p>");
 }
function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
 if(!empty($name)&& !empty($cname)&&!empty($mobileno)&& !empty($email)&&!empty($city)&&!empty($postalcode)&&!empty($address)){
   header('Location: Submission.php?$submit=1');
   exit();}


?>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="div1" class="fluid"><!-- header ends here-->
    <div id="header" class="fluid">
      <div class="fluid logo_container zeroMargin_tablet">
      <div class="fluid logo_mvc"></div>
      <!-- logo_mvc ends here-->
      <div class="fluid logo_gsm"></div>
      <!-- logo_gsm ends here-->
    </div>
    <!-- logo_container ends here-->
</div>
    <div class="fluid imageslide zeroMargin_desktop">
      <div class="fluid imageslide_gs zeroMargin_desktop"></div>
      <!-- imageslide_gs ends here-->
      <div class="fluid imageslide_content">
      <h1>IP Product Introduction and VoIP PBX
Appliance Training Day @ Toronto</h1>
      </div><!-- imageslide_content ends here-->
      <div class="fluid imageslide_product"></div>
      <!-- imageslide_product ends here-->
    </div><!-- imageslide ends here-->
    <div class="fluid content">
    <div class="fluid content_det">
    <h3>Event information</h3>
    <p>Please join us at the Fairfield Inn & Suites Toronto Airport where Grandstream will offer four different sessions during the day. </p>
    <h3>Introduction to Grandstream IP products</h3>
    <p><b>8:45am - 10:15am</b><br/>
Introduction to Grandstream, and basic information on Grandstream products including ATAs, gateways, routers and telephones. </p>
<h3>Introduction to IP cameras IP and Surveillance products</h3>
    <p><b>12:45pm - 2:15pm</b><br/>
Basic information on IP cameras and surveillance products, and the introduction of the brand new GVR3550 Network Video Recorder. </p>
<h3>Advanced Technical Training for UCM VoIP PBX's</h3>
    <p><b>2:30pm - 4:30pm</b><br/>
This session will focus on the advanced features of the UCM series, including the new features of the upcoming software and the brand new UCM6510 VoIP PBX for T1 networks. </p>
    </div><!-- content_det ends here--><div class="fluid contet_form">

    <h2>Register Now</h2>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>First name *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name Here" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>

    </div>


    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Company Name *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="cname" placeholder="Enter Your Company Name Here" value="<?php echo $cname; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $cnameErr;?></span></div>

    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Mobile Number *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="mobileno" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number Here" value="<?php echo $mobileno; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $mobilenoErr?></span>
     </div>

    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Email Id *:</b></label>
    <input type="email" size="20px" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id Here" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr?></span></div>


    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>City *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="city" placeholder="Enter Your City Name Here" value="<?php echo $city;?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $cityErr?></span></div>

    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Postal Code *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="postalcode" placeholder="Enter Postal Code Here" value="<?php echo $postalcode; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $postalcodeErr?></span>
     </div>

    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Address *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="address" placeholder="Enter Address Here" value="<?php echo $address; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $addressErr?></span></div>


<button name="submit" >Submit</button>
    </form>

    </div><!-- contet_form ends here-->
    </div><!-- content ends here-->
  </div><!-- div1 ends here-->
</div>
</body>
```

**And here Submission.php Code**

```
<?php 
$submit=1;
if( !isset($_POST[$submit]) )
 {

 }
 else{
  header('Location:index.php');
   exit;
 }
 ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Thank You For Registration</title>
</head>

<body>
<h4>Registration Sucessfull</h4><br/>
<a href="index.php">Go To Registration Page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you using .com.com twice ? Is this the TO email id

Comment: No that i have type by mistake, in code it is proper, i have edited it now

Comment: please remove the . after the com

Comment: Hi @sandeepSK Can you tell me what are the fileds available in the form you are not sending the submitted details to mail so its not coming

Comment: I have tested your code and the mail came from from@from.com

Comment: @Choco i have tested its working but,i need to form data to be in body, can please tell how to do it, for eg: once user fills first name and clicks on send i want user name to be in body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First The problem is its an html email so use correct headers for it and then send the form data which you want in the body of html file

Test with this and let me know whether its working

```
    $to = 'from@from.com';
    $subject = 'I need to show html'; 
    $from ='from@from.com'; 
    ini_set("sendmail_from", $from);
    $username=$_POST['name'];
    $mobilenum=$_POST['mobileno'];
    $cname=$_POST['cname'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $postalcode=$_POST['postalcode'];
    $headers = "From: " .$from. "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from. "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $body = '<p style=color:red;>This text should be red</p>';
    $body.='<label>User Name:</label>'.$username.'<br>';
    $body .= '<label>Mobile Num:</label>'.$mobilenum.'<br>';
    $body .= '<label>Company Name:</label>'.$cname.'<br>';
    $body .= '<label>Address:</label>'.$address.'<br>';
    $body .= '<label>Postalcode:</label>'.$postalcode.'<br>';

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {

  echo("<p>Sent</p>");
 } else {
  echo("<p>Error...</p>");
 }
```

Comment: its working but i have around 5 field ,only first name or username data is coming to my mail id, others are not getting into mail,i have used similar method of Concatenation

Comment: Suppose you have suggestions field Add like this the other 5 fields also $body.='<label>Suggestions:</label>'.$_POST['suggestions'].'<br>';

Comment: and how to get proper text format, i am getting it with html tags

Comment: Edit your question with the form you have then I will check

Comment: I have tried its working but its not properly formatted, i am getting lable tag

Comment: Did you try with the answer which I provided it will not get the label tag I have tested it

Comment: i have given everything same except the default values for $Username and others

Comment: Ok @sandeepSK Again I have edited it please use that and tell me

Comment: i am still having the same problem

Comment: Can you give me your email id So that I will be contacting you